# solr highlighting: overlapped html tags

Tags: solr, lucene

I HAVE to highlight html text returned from solr v6.6.2

original html stored in `body_txt_en` field in solr:

```html
I have a strong <strong>TCL</strong> code
```

highlight /select parameters:

```
hl.q=have strong TCL
hl=on
hl.fl=*_txt_en
```

expected result:

```html
I <em>have</em> a <em>strong</em> <strong><em>TCL<em/></strong> code
```

real result:

```html
I <em>have</em> a <em>strong</em> <strong><em>TCL</strong><em/> code
```

As you can see - `</em>` appeared after `</strong>` that breaks html for large documents.

field configuration:

```xml
    <dynamicField name="*_txt_en" type="text_en"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

All other solr parameters/configs are default for version 6.6.2

Analysis on indexing gives:
[image]

Can't understand why after `solr.StandardTokenizerFactory` (`ST`) `end - start = 12` for `TCL` keyword

Question:
How to solve this "wrong html tag order" issue?

Comment: Use an `update.chain` with the [HTMLStripFieldUpdateProcessorFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/update-request-processors.html#fieldmutatingupdateprocessorfactory-derived-factories) instead - that way the text will be stripped of HTML _before_ being given to the field, and the stored value should be without any signs of the HTML at all. This would however remove any HTML returned from the field as well.

Comment: Also, see [LUCENE-5734](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-5734) where this exact issue is discussed (and it includes a custom charfilter that puts the end token offset at `<` instead of after `>`.

Comment: @MatsLindh,  That's really helpful! Thanks to your hints I did workaround that works for my case: `<charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="&lt;[^>]+>" replacement=" "/>` before `HTMLStripCharFilterFactory`. Good to know that jira ticket is there.